# Draggable bootstarp's table row with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, draggable

I have a table and I need that after click on some button the rows will be draggable.
I have the following Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#edit').click(function () {
  $('table a').css("cursor", "default");
  $('table tr').draggable();
});
```

The broblem is that I'm not seeing the row as draggable, but on the browswer dev tools I do see a change un the position : http://screencast.com/t/VZq1YKp2AKW

Wish for help, thanks!

Comment: Please provide a fiddle, something to work on....

Comment: What do you want to do after dragging it?

Comment: @TheLittlePig Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nmDT/3/

Comment: @NikhilBaliga I just want to change the row's order in the table, and than save the new order using AJAX

Comment: I don't think you can do that with tables. All standard examples use sortable on ul & li. I'll try looking around though

Comment: You can refer this demo may be it can help: http://jsfiddle.net/fwjaj/